# OAuth Facebook authorization account?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

Is there a way for facebook to create an authorization account for users who do not have a facebook account? I do not want to store any passwords on my server. When the user logs in to my website, I want them to also log in using facebook authorization. Is this even possible? Are users force to have a facebook profile for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately yes.  Pages require admins (auth users) to have their own personal facebook account.  You could always create one facebook account as a generic authorized user to log into..

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, Facebook does not provide what you looking for. The user must have a Facebook account in order to use Facebook authentication on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a facebook app and associate with your web site, you can authenticate pages via your app (with your APP_ID AND SECRET_KEY).

Look into creating your facebook app.  It's really just a matter of getting app_id and secret_key keys.

Then anybody, logged in or not, a facebook user or not, can look at the material that your app/site authenticated.